# Multiple Page view controllers in UItableview, when I select or swipe page I am not getting cell indexpath?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

- In UITableview, multiple page view controller and different content like array.
- first time it's displaying fine, because first time I am always passing index = 0 for all cells (arrays).
- but for example after scroll and scroll-down in tableview, In current Address section: 3 pages is there, here I want to pass respected array based on cell index path array, but **I am not able to get cell (page) index path**.
- if I know cell indexpath based on that I will pass respected data to contentpageviewcontroller.

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      var cell: UITableViewCell!
      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pageviewCell", for: indexPath)

      self.pageViewController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController"))! as! UIPageViewController
      self.pageViewController.delegate = self
      self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
      self.pageViewController.title = "\(indexPath.row-1)"
      pageViewController.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(index: 0, indexPath: indexPath.row-1)], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
      pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width-10, height: cell.contentView.frame.size.height-10)

      self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
      cell.contentView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
      self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

      return cell
  }

  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
  {
      let pageContent: ProfilePageContentVC = viewController as! ProfilePageContentVC

      var index = pageContent.pageIndex
      if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
      {
          return nil
      }
      index -= 1;
      return getViewControllerAtIndex(index: index, indexPath: Int(pageViewController.title!)!)
  }

  func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
  {
      let pageContent: ProfilePageContentVC = viewController as! ProfilePageContentVC

      var index = pageContent.pageIndex
      if (index == NSNotFound)
      {
          return nil;
      }
      index += 1;
      let val: NSString = pageListCountChkDict.value(forKey: self.pageViewController.title!) as! NSString
      //if (index == arrPageTitle.count)
      if (index == val.integerValue)
      {
          return nil;
      }
      return getViewControllerAtIndex(index: index, indexPath: Int(pageViewController.title!)!)
  }

  func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger, indexPath: NSInteger) -> ProfilePageContentVC {

      let pageContentViewController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfilePageContentVC"))! as! ProfilePageContentVC

      pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

      let pageContentDict = NSMutableDictionary()
      let pageContentFinalArray = NSMutableArray()

      if objModel.finalDict.allKeys[indexPath] as! String == "EMPOFFHR" {
          pageContentFinalArray.add(pageContentDict)
          pageContentViewController.pageContentFinalArray = pageContentFinalArray as NSArray
          let pageTitleArray = ["HR Details"]
          pageContentViewController.pageTitleArray = pageTitleArray as NSArray
      }

      func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

          let val: NSString = pageListCountChkDict.value(forKey: self.pageViewController.title!) as! NSString
          print("presentationCount :\(self.pageViewController.title!)")
          print("presentationCount :\(val)")
          return val.integerValue
      }


      func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
          return 0
      }
  ```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it was introduced when you created your question, or whether this is really the case in your code, but `presentationCount` and `presentationIndex` are defined inside `getViewControllerAtIndex`. Are you missing a `}` in there?

Comment: Have you got any success?